# Entities with the same name

Tags: xml, entities

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no" ?>
<!ENTITY logo "logo1">
<!ENTITY logo "logo2">
<!ENTITY logo "logo3">
```

It is able to parse and do this with any xml verison? And what would happen if i used &test?

Answer (score 2):

See the spec https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-entity-decl, it says "If the same entity is declared more than once, the first declaration encountered is binding; at user option, an XML processor MAY issue a warning if entities are declared multiple times.". So what you have is allowed, the first declaration is binding, you might get a warning.